# loop to detect usb drive storage

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive, batch-file, cmd.exe

This is my loop to detect usb drive storage:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM get removable loaded drives:
for /f %%a in ('"wmic logicaldisk where (drivetype=2 and size is not null) get caption,size 2>nul|find ":""') do set usb=!usb! %%a
```

Detects most usb drive storage. But there are some who do not detected (fat32 greater than 16 GB or external drives NTFS 500mb 1 tb, etc)

I think the problem relates to "DRIVETYPE"

```
Value   Meaning
  0     Unknown
  1     No root directory
  2     Removable disk
  3     Local disk
  4     Network drive
  5     Compact disk
  6     RAM disk
```

Example: fat32 usb devices 32GB storage, lists it as fixed disk (not as Removable Disk) with:

```
wmic logicaldisk get description,name
```

SO: Win 7/8/8.1/10

How I can make the loop detects all USB storage devices? Thanks

Comment: are they enumerated when you query `wmic logicaldisk` ?

Comment: yes the lists, but usb fat32 32GB as fixed disk (not as Removable Disk)

Answer (score 2):

Your code can't work because you are setting setlocal, so no vars survive the batch. On the other hand you don't use delims or tokens, by default the `delims=` is space and `tokens=1`. If you put a `set usb` as the last line you would get only `Usb= E:` (with a leading space).
As there aren't to many possible drives I'd do the filtering via batch and use the simpler `wmic logicaldisk list brief`

Which tokens to use is up to you.

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "USB="
REM get removable loaded drives:
for /f "tokens=1-5" %%a in (
 'wmic logicaldisk list brief'
) do if %%b Equ 2 if %%d gtr 0 Set USB=!USB! %%a
Echo:Usb removable drives:%USB%
EndLocal&Set USB=%USB:~1%&Goto :Eof
```

**EDIT** added an Echo to show the gathered USB drives.

```
> Get-UsbDrives.cmd
Usb removable drives:  E:
```

HTH

Comment: thanks but I only want to show the letter of the USB storage device detected (such as F:)

Comment: That still doesn't work for all USB drives. I have one external USB (3TB) which has drivetype = 3. I don't know of a way around this. In addition your code doesn't return anything for my Sandisk thumb drive ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Since my batch filters for drivetype 2 that one is clear. Does wmic on cmd line show your Sandisk drives?

Comment: Of course. My own batch file does the job perfectly :) https://i.imgur.com/m40lUFV.png

Comment: Output from yours https://i.imgur.com/WCL1xqc.png

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, according to the OPs first attempt I changed the batch to gather all USBdrives in the var USB and save it following endlocal in the original environment. Since there is no Echo this is invisible. I'll insert an echo for the doubting Thomas. ;-)